# Ubuntu 12.10 and Macbook Air 1,1 - no sound (speakers + microphone) - headphone OK

Tags: 12.10, sound, alsa, macbook

I ran `lspci | grep Audio` and got:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

I've searched the forums and added the following line to `alsa.conf`

```
# macbook air sound
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp3
```

I rebooted and there was still no sound.

So I ran `alsamixer`. It shows that the speakers and master are not muted. The speakers and microphone are still not working. What can I do to get them to work? I'm running a single-boot Ubuntu 12.10 system with a 64-bit kernel, on a Macbook Air 1.1.

I also ran the command hwinfo and got the following results

'hwinfo --sound

> hal.1: read hal dataprocess 2630: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
>   This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
>   libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
>   13: PCI 1b.0: 0403 Audio device
>     [Created at pci.318]
>     Unique ID: u1Nb.4u0CAOk3K5C
>     SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0
>     SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1b.0
>     Hardware Class: sound
>     Model: "Intel 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller"
>     Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
>     Device: pci 0x284b "82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller"
>     SubVendor: pci 0x106b "Apple Computer Inc."
>     SubDevice: pci 0x00a2 
>     Revision: 0x03
>     Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
>     Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
>     Memory Range: 0x90500000-0x90503fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
>     IRQ: 43 (338 events)
>     Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d0000284Bsv0000106Bsd000000A2bc04sc03i00"
>     Driver Info #0:
>       Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
>       Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
>     Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown'

Comment: The same problem persists in Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) and Macbook Air 1,1. 

Furthermore, a bug has been filed for a similar issue with the Macbook Air 2,1 here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1181828